# Mongoid fill out referenced ids

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, autocomplete, mongoid

I'm building an autocomplete feature for my rails app. The input form makes an ajax call on keypress which then calls this search method in rails

```
def search
    search = Regexp.new(params[:name])
    @users = User.where(:name=>search)

    render :json => @users
  end
```

All works fine... However, the user has a bunch of fields that are foreign keys to other collections.

For example, one of these fields is for rolify. `role_ids` which looks like `"role_ids" : [ObjectId("508eee5afa0d00b818000001"), ObjectId("508eee92fa0d00b818000002")]` which each map to something like `administrator` or `moderator`

What I want to do is replace these ids with the actual document from the roles collection. I know I can just manually fill it out, but I was hoping that there would be some way with Mongoid to automatically populate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haven't used Mongoid myself, but with ActiveRecord you would do it like this:

```
render :json => @users, :include => [:roles]
```

This of course needs your `User` model to have `roles` association set.

Hope this is relevant in Mongoid too.